# How to use smooth scrolling?

Tags: html, css, scroll, smoothing

I want the web to scroll down once the "I want to Donate!" button is clicked by the user. How can I do that?

```css
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
    <div class="slideshow-container">

        <div class="mySlides fade">
          <img src="image1.jpg" style="width:100%">
          <div class="text1"><strong>"No One Has Ever Become Poor By Giving"</strong><br></div>
          <div class="text2"> Every donation will be used to buy nutritious food for those in need.<br>
                              You can change the world together with us!</div> 
         <div class="main" id="section1">
         <button class="scrolling-button" href="#section2"> I want to Donate!</button>
         </div>
        </div>
    
    <div class="ourform" id="section2">
          <form action="/">
            
            <h1> Donation Form</h1>
```

The result:

[image]

can someone tell me what mistake did i do and how to fix this? coz its not working.

Comment: Unless i'm missing something your problem is unrelated to smooth scrolling; there isn't any element in there that would even give a reason to initiate scrolling (be it smooth or not) ? `<button href...>` doesn't exist, you likely wanted to use `<a href="#section2"><button ...></a>`

Comment: `button` have no `href` attribute. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: @Raxi  Noted. Thanks for the clear explanation.